# Retrieve Google user and use it as data in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

**What I have now**: I have a static HTML site where I'm creating a dashboard with Google Data Studio. The spreadsheet connected to Google Data Studio has sensitive data of 100s of different users, each identified by their e-mail address in the organization.

**Goal**: Display only the rows of a table where a user's e-mail is stated. I want to do it retrieving the user e-mail from session, passing it to Google Data Studio and automatically show rows corresponding to the address.

**Code snippet**: 

- Retrieve the user's e-mail from session:

`var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`

But this is all I know. **I don't know:**
- Wether I have to make a connector, write it on Google Apps scripts then link it or write it in the Spreadsheets Apps Script (makes no sense for me).
- How to send the 'email' retrieved to Google Data Studio.

Any lights on this issue would be really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to retrieve the active user's email unless there are certain conditions. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) we can read that:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
>   User.getEmail() returns a blank string.
>
> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for
>   example, the user's email address is not available in any context that
>   allows a script to run without that user's authorization...
>
> ...these restrictions generally do not apply **if the developer runs the
>   script themselves** or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

This means you would need to deploy the script as a web app with the option:

**Execute the app as:** *User accessing the web app*

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?linkId=82226488) feature was launched last week. This can be a much simpler solution to your requirements.

**Original Answer:** Implement [Row level filtering with Data Studio](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering). However, instead of using BigQuery as your source of data, fetch the data from the associated Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. ***Data Set***: [Done] In the the spreadsheet, create a field (e.g. email) which includes an email address on each row.
2. ***Data Source***: At the Data Source (editing an existing or creating a new one) the top left now includes an [email filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766) where the field with the email address (email) can be selected as the field to filter the report by.